# "npm run build-storybook" returns error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: vite, storybook, vite-reactjs

I have a react project built with Vite. I just added a storybook by "**npx storybook@latest init**", so added "**npm install @storybook/builder-vite --save-dev**".

I can run storybook locally by "npm run storybook", it works well

BUT when I build a static storybook page by "**npm run build-storybook**" I get an generated folder "storybook-static", and **the following error**:

```
@storybook/cli v7.5.2

info => Cleaning outputDir: /storybook-static
info => Loading presets
info => Building manager..
info => Manager built (77 ms)
info => Building preview..
info => Copying static files: /Users/dk/Dev/bli-ui/node_modules/@storybook/manager/static at /Users/dk/Dev/bli-ui/storybook-static/sb-common-assets
=> Failed to build the preview //  The error starts here
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>)
    at configResolved (file://./node_modules/vite-plugin-dts/dist/index.mjs:581:100)
    at file://./node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:66031:28
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveConfig (file://./node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:66031:14)
    at async build (file://./node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:47926:20)
    at async build (./node_modules/@storybook/builder-vite/dist/index.js:159:11030)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Module.build2 (./node_modules/@storybook/builder-vite/dist/index.js:159:13349)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

My main.js file:

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react-vite'

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-vite',
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag',
  },
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-vite', 
  },
}
export default config
```

What is wrong here? I tried to google but did not find any help.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed caused by 'vite-plugin-lib-inject-css'. You can exclude the offending plugin from the Storybook build using the `withoutVitePlugins` helper in your Storybook config.

```
import { withoutVitePlugins } from '@storybook/builder-vite'
...
const config: StorybookConfig = {
    ...
    async viteFinal(config) {
        return {
            ...config,
            plugins: await withoutVitePlugins(config.plugins, ['vite:lib-inject-css']),
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

do you use 'vite-plugin-lib-inject-css'? I had the same problem as you and removing it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue ([#15](https://github.com/emosheeep/vite-plugin-lib-inject-css/issues/15)) with the plugin `vite-plugin-lib-inject-css` and has been fixed in version `2.0.0`, you should be fine if you update the plugin to the latest version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).